# Azure container apps in same environment, ingress limited to container app environment 403 http error

Tags: c#, reactjs, azure, asp.net-core, .net-8.0

I am using the REACT app for the front end and ASP.NET app for the back end. I deploy them as container apps in the same container app environment and resource group. Ingress for the React app is set to public. When ingress is set to public for the backend app, the backend gets the request and sends a good response. When ingress is set to limited to the app environment I get an HTTP 403 error and message:
"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled".
In general headers I get "Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin".

In the backend container app, I ticked Access-Control-Allow-Origin and set it to allow all Origins, methods, and headers (in input fields I wrote '*').
How do I fix this problem?

I followed Microsoft documentation, found tutorials on YouTube, and looked up similar questions on Stackoverflow, but nothing gave results.

Comment: Since you're running in a container I assume you're talking about ASP.NET Core? Which .NET version are you on?

Comment: If you do not proxy the request from your React frontend to the backend (or have a separate reverse-proxy in-between which does the routing) and you don't make the backend publicly accessible it won't work, since the request then comes from outside of the environment. If you proxy it should work. If you don't want to proxy, you need to some public endpoints for your frontend to call. That's one of the drawbacks of SPAs. If you're using React Server Components with server-side data fetching by using e.g. Next.js you don't necessarily need that.

Comment: I am on .NET 8.0. I added proxy server using npm install http-proxy-middleware and now I have a new problem. Proxy works when I start the environment on localhost, but when I deploy it application reads index.js not the data from backend.